# program wont read at second scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I dont understand where I went wrong. It does not read at second `scanf()` just skips on to the next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14

int main()
{
    int y='y', choice,radius;
    char read_y;
    float area, circum;

do_again:
    printf("Enter the radius for the circle to calculate area and circumfrence \n");
    scanf("%d",&radius);
    area = (float)radius*(float)radius*PI;
    circum = 2*(float)radius*PI;

    printf("The radius of the circle is %d for which the area is %8.4f and circumfrence is %8.4f \n", radius, area, circum);

    printf("Please enter 'y' if you want to do another calculation\n");
    scanf ("%c",&read_y);
    choice=read_y;
    if (choice==y)
        goto do_again;
    else
        printf("good bye");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't use gotos

Comment: `goto do_again;` We are in 21st century !!!!!

Comment: why shouldn't i be using goto

Comment: @TheNewIdiot "goto do_again; We are in 21st century !!!!!" what do you mean.. why goto should not be used

Comment: because http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: because http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 10):

Your first scanf() leaves a newline in the input stream which is consumed by the next scanf() when you read a char.

Change

```
scanf ("%c",&read_y);
```

to

```
scanf (" %c",&read_y); // Notice the whitespace
```

which will ignore all whitespaces.

---

In general, avoid scanf() for reading inputs (especially when mixing different formats as do here). Instead use **[fgets()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html)** and parse it using [**sscanf()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html).

Comment: There's nothing that prevents you from using scanf(). Just that using it can lead to formatting issues because scanf() doesn't handle input failures very well.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.14

void clear_buffer( void );

int main()
{
    int y='y',choice,radius;
    char read_y;
    float area, circum;
    do_again:
        printf("Enter the radius for the circle to calculate area and circumfrence \n");        
        scanf("%d",&radius);        
        area = (float)radius*(float)radius*PI;
        circum = 2*(float)radius*PI;    
        printf("The radius of the circle is %d for which the area is %8.4f and circumfrence is %8.4f \n", radius, area, circum);
        printf("Please enter 'y' if you want to do another calculation\n"); 
        clear_buffer();
        scanf("%c",&read_y);            
        choice=read_y;      
    if ( choice==y )
        goto do_again;
    else
        printf("good bye\n");
    return 0;
}

void clear_buffer( void )
{
     int ch;

     while( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF );
}
```

or you can write fflush(Stdin) before scanf

Comment: will add it to my notes.. i am new commer learning.. thanks for helping

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, because it is only defined for ouput streams